# Border color on Border-radius for safari

Tags: html, border, css

I am trying to apply a border and a border color for a div with a border-radius. It works for all browsers except for safari. In safari the border radius work but the border and border color get messed up. Here is my code

```
#profilePic{
    border-radius: 100%; 
    border: 3px solid #fff; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: background and border colors are same - white. are you sure border is not shown? try changing to 2 different colors for test.

Answer (score 1):

have try to draw the border with a `box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px white;` to avoid that gap  sometimes appearing in safari ?
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/details/jbxDo